# Simple input error

Tags: python

having a issue with a input error
Just giving them options of what they wanna input instead of yes or no
code:

```
def getMode():
    while True:
        print('do you wish to encrypt or decrypt a message?')
        mode = input().lower()
        if mode in [ 'encrypt', 'e', 'decrypt', 'd']:
            return mode
         else:
            print('Enter either "encrypt or "e" or "decrypt", "d".')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gomcrai/pythings/caesarCipher.py", line 46, in <module>
    mode = getMode()
  File "/Users/gomcrai/pythings/caesarCipher.py", line 8, in getMode
    mode = input().lower()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'e' is not defined
```

Only thing happening on line 46 is the function is being called

Comment: Is this Python 2?